# Remove paragraph from file

Tags: bash, shell, text-processing, sed

I have a file (`file.php`) like this:

```
...
Match user foo
        ChrootDirectory /NAS/foo.info/
        ForceCommand internal-sftp
        AllowTcpForwarding no
        GatewayPorts no
        X11Forwarding no



Match user bar
        ChrootDirectory /NAS/bar.co.uk/
        ForceCommand internal-sftp
        AllowTcpForwarding no
        GatewayPorts no
        X11Forwarding no



Match user baz
        ChrootDirectory /NAS/baz.com/
        ForceCommand internal-sftp
        AllowTcpForwarding no
        GatewayPorts no
        X11Forwarding no
```

I am trying to write a bash script to delete one of the paragraphs.

---

So say I wanted delete the user `foo` from the `file.php`. After running the script, it would then look like this:

```
...
Match user bar
        ChrootDirectory /NAS/bar.co.uk/
        ForceCommand internal-sftp
        AllowTcpForwarding no
        GatewayPorts no
        X11Forwarding no



Match user baz
        ChrootDirectory /NAS/baz.com/
        ForceCommand internal-sftp
        AllowTcpForwarding no
        GatewayPorts no
        X11Forwarding no
```

How could I go about doing this. I have thought about using `sed` but that only seems to be appropriate for one liners?

```
sed -i 's/foo//g' file.php
```

And I couldn't do it for each individual line as most of the lines withing the paragraph are not unique! Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, I rejected your edit without realizing you were the OP. In any case, I don't like giving the `-i` switch without explicitly stating that it will change the original file. I have now included it.

Comment: Haha fair enough! Thank you for answering!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Actually, `sed` can also take ranges. This command will delete all lines between `Match user foo` and the first empty line (inclusive):

```
$ sed '/Match user foo/,/^\s*$/{d}' file


Match user bar
        ChrootDirectory /NAS/bar.co.uk/
        ForceCommand internal-sftp
        AllowTcpForwarding no
        GatewayPorts no
        X11Forwarding no



Match user baz
        ChrootDirectory /NAS/baz.com/
        ForceCommand internal-sftp
        AllowTcpForwarding no
        GatewayPorts no
        X11Forwarding no
```

Personally, however, I would do this using perl's paragraph mode (`-00`) that has the benefit of removing the leading blank lines:

```
$ perl -00ne 'print unless /Match user foo/' file
Match user bar
        ChrootDirectory /NAS/bar.co.uk/
        ForceCommand internal-sftp
        AllowTcpForwarding no
        GatewayPorts no
        X11Forwarding no

Match user baz
        ChrootDirectory /NAS/baz.com/
        ForceCommand internal-sftp
        AllowTcpForwarding no
        GatewayPorts no
        X11Forwarding no
```

In both cases, you can use `-i` to edit the file in place (these will create a backup of the original called `file.bak`):

```
sed -i.bak '/Match user foo/,/^\s*$/{d}' file
```

or

```
perl -i.bak -00ne 'print unless /Match user foo/' file
```

Answer (score 5):

Slightly more complicated than terdon’s `sed` answer:

```
awk '/foo/ {suppress=1} /^\s*$/ {suppress=0} !suppress' file.php
```

produces almost exactly the same result as terdon’s answer:

```
...



Match user bar
        ChrootDirectory /NAS/bar.co.uk/
        ForceCommand internal-sftp
        AllowTcpForwarding no
        GatewayPorts no
        X11Forwarding no



Match user baz
        ChrootDirectory /NAS/baz.com/
        ForceCommand internal-sftp
        AllowTcpForwarding no
        GatewayPorts no
        X11Forwarding no
```

i.e., it deletes (suppresses) every line
starting with the one that matches `foo`
up *to* the first subsequent line that contains only whitespace. 
Lines 8, 9, and 10, which are blank in the `file.php` input file
(between `user foo` and `user bar`) come out in the output. 
By contrast, terdon’s answer deletes every line
starting with the one that matches `foo`
up *through* the first subsequent line that contains only whitespace;
so line 8 is deleted, but 9 and 10 come through.

These are not exactly what the user asked for.

```
awk '/foo/ {suppress=1}
     /^\s*$/ && suppress==1 {suppress=2}
     /[^\s]/ && suppress==2 {suppress=0}
     !suppress' file.php
```

is.  (This is broken into multiple lines for readability;
it could be entered all on one line.) 
When it sees `foo`, it goes into suppress mode #1 (`suppress=1`). 
When it sees a blank line while in suppress mode #1,
it switches into suppress mode #2. 
When it sees a non-blank line while in suppress mode #2,
it switches into mode 0. 
Finally, it does the obvious — print lines that are not `suppress`ed.

Comment: Nice little finite state automaton here.