# Remove block of lines from file with awk

Tags: awk

I have a file looking like:

```
---
some metadata
...
---
Some real content.
...
Important content.
```

Expected output:

```
Some real content.
...
Important content.
```

To keep things simple, let's consider that strictly `/^---$/` lines are not happening anywhere else than as beginning and end delimiters of the heading metadata block. As shown above.

Note: there could be any amounts of new lines between the end `---` delimeter and the first line of content. In that case, I don't care in keeping the new lines or not.

I would like to preferably use `awk` because I feel this command is versatile and powerful enough to help me do more manipulations on the file if I need later.

Based on [this answer to another similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/192557/37457), I've tried the following unsuccessfully:

```bsh
awk '/---/ {s=1} /---/ && s==1 {s=0} !s' $file
```

Might it be because the second rule is actually matching the first line of the file, again?

Is there another way to efficiently do this with `awk`?

Comment: Have a look at https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/10374, does it answer your question?

Comment: @Quasímodo some of the answers there are providing actual solutions to the problem, indeed. But things are framed differently, and the accepted answer below is much closer to what I had tried before, as mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about the following:

```
awk 'BEGIN { metadata = 0 } /---/ { metadata = !metadata; next } !metadata' FILE
```

With the following input `FILE` (I added more lines):

```
---
some metadata
...
---
Some real content.
...
Important content.
---
some metadata
...
---
1
2
3
```

it prints:

```
Some real content.
...
Important content.
1
2
3
```

Your script:

```
awk '/---/ {s=1} /---/ && s==1 {s=0} !s' $file
```

doesn't work because you first set `s` to 1:

```
/---/ {s=1}
```

you *immediately* set it to 0:

```
/---/ && s==1 {s=0}
```

and print record if `!s`, IOW `!0` so at the end of the day you print
each line.

Comment: You can completely delete the `BEGIN` block since ordinary Awk variables are unset by default.

Comment: Yes but I want to avoid `awk: ./script.awk:8: (FILENAME=FILE FNR=1) warning: reference to uninitialized variable `metadata'` when running with `--lint`

Answer (score 2):

**GNU sed** employing extended regexes
To be read as delete from dash-dash to dash-dash.

```
sed -Ee '
  /^-+$/,/^-+$/d
' file
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not an awk solution, however try sed for best result:

```
sed '/^---$/,/^---$/d' $file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '/^---$/ && s++<2{ next } s>1 && NF' infile
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed '/metadata/,+2d' filename| sed '/---/d'
```

input

```
---
some metadata
...
---
Some real content.
...
Important content.
---
some metadata
...
---
1
2
3
```

output

```
Some real content.
...
Important content.
1
2
3
```

Comment: Your answer assumes that the metadata consists of exactly two lines starting with the keyword `metadata`. It would be worthwile to add this explanation to your post, since the OP will have to modify any answer to adapt it to the actual file format, and also because in case the number of lines is not fixed (which is probable since otherwise no "block-start" and "block-end" markers would be necessary), this answer wouldn't work.